# Como puedo usar mi app hosteada en cualquier dispositivo?

Tags: login, hosting, devices

Hice el deploy de mi app con el stack MERN en Hostinger la cual tiene un login en el home.
Cuando la abro en mi computadora donde la desarrolle, me funciona perfecto pero cuando quiero abrirla en mi celu o cualquier otro dispositivo me abre el home pero me arroja usuario o contraseña incorrecta al intentar logearme

Alguien sabe que puedo modificar? Es mi primer deploy. Gracias

Comment: ¿Puede ser un problema de cors? Puedes probarlo en otro dispositivo y checkear en la consola si al intentar logearte te está dando un error?

Comment: No queda claro si la aplicación remota funciona probándola desde el dispositivo donde la desarrollaste o si hablas de la prueba en local. En cualquier caso, puede que los datos en remoto no sean los mismos (base de datos) y de ahí el error. Deberías verificar si ese usuario / contraseña existen en la base de datos remota.

Comment: Perdon pero soy nuevo en esto. Estuve leyendo y volviendome loco y por lo que vi, es un error de cors. Lo probe en otra computadora y me sale el cartel de : " Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null) "

Comment: Tengo la base de datos en Mongo con mi cluster y dudo que sea ese el problema. Aclaro, la aplicacion la abro desde mi computadora y funciona perfecto. Cuando la quiero abrir desde otra computadora o mi celular no me toma los usuarios, no se si es que el problema de CORS hace que no lea mi base de datos ! Es mi primer deploy

Comment: En muchos lados lei que lo solucionan con : app.use(cors()); o incluso agregando el "proxy" pero intente todo y no puedo arreglarlo